# Unresolved external symbol with QImage in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, unresolved-external, linkage, qimage

I get linkage error in Qt Creator when I want to use QImage.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <Qt>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtWidgets/QtWidgets>
#include <QtGui/QImage>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QImage *image = new QImage();
    // or QImage *image = new QImage("missile2.jpg");

    return a.exec();
}
```

and this is project file

```
QT       += core
QT       += gui

TARGET = RGBLayers
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Can anyone help me what is the problem please?

Comment: you shouldn’t have linking problem with a correct Qt setup. use `qmake -query` to list environment variables (see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-environment-reference.html). Can you make sure Qt dll are at the location of the variable `QT_INSTALL_LIBS`

Comment: `QT_INSTALL_LIBS:C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\lib`. and there are lib files.

Comment: Could you post the link error?

Comment: Do you have another Qt install on the machine?

Comment: Maybe. I have installed Qt for android. Never mind I use some external library for image processing. Thank you for your help.